# Prove center of a group is a subgroup using one-step subgroup test

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing

I'm not sure if this is correct. It doesn't seem so.

If $a,b  \in C$, then we must show $ab^{-1} \in C$.

$$ab^{-1}x=axb^{-1}=xab^{-1}$$

This doesn't seem correct. I've seen two-step subgroup tests of this proof and the one-step test I'm doing just looks like I'm skipping a step. Am I applying this one-step test correctly?

Comment: You should also check your 'subgroup' is non-empty. The test doesn't work otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ab^{-1}x=b^{-1}ax=b^{-1}xa=(x^{-1}b)^{-1}a=(bx^{-1})^{-1}a=xb^{-1}a=xab^{-1}$